# How to add an angular component present in a different angular app on demand (no libraries to be used)?

Tags: angular, webpack

I have a scenario, where I have two independent angular projects being independently deployed. I have a button in one component present in one angular app. I need to load a component or a module (present in different angular project) on the button click. The challenge is I don't have idea on how to load the component on demand present in different independent project. I don't think libraries are suitable in this scenario. Some help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked into Angular Elements? That allows you to compile angular components into standard HTML web components, that can be used everywhere

Comment: Thanks @ThorJacobsen for reply. I studied and trying to implement angular elements. But faced some issues. Wil let you know once implementation is done.